# show results after switch_inline_query

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I create an inline kayboard in my bot:

```
$keyboard = array(
"inline_keyboard" => array(array(array("text" => "My Button Text", "switch_inline_query" => "my text")))
);
$keyboard = json_encode($keyboard, true);
```

how show result after click this keyboard ?

Comment: I can't understand your new question, do you mean "Voted" like official @like bot?

Comment: yes how create a vote bot

Comment: which api for show result in telegram bot?

Answer (score 0):

**Not possible** at this time.

No matter what inline keyboard contents you send, forward it won't attaching that.

Inline keyboard will disappear after forward even official [@like](https://t.me/like) bot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean Notification Text, you can add `text` and optional `show_alert` to answerCallbackQuery.

Also, you can use [editMessageText](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagetext) method to edit your message.

For more details, you can lookup [answerCallbackQuery](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#answercallbackquery) reference.